# Why doesn't Canada try to make its population grow up to the size of the USA?

Tags: canada, population

This is my personal assessment:  The USA has a moderately large population, and it is the world's largest economy because of that. As a result, the USA is a superpower.

No other countries in the West have this potential except Canada. Coz, other countries don't have enough land space to accommodate a large population and keep the density comfortable for its inhabitants. Australia has a huge landmass, but it is mostly an arid desert and uninhabitable as a result.

[image]

The following map shows the comparative density of the population of Canada and the USA:

[image]

It seems that most of Canada is empty.

I see that their population growth is big. But, this is not enough to make them a Great power (e.g. UK, France, Japan) or a superpower.

Why doesn't Canada try to make its population grow up to the size of the USA?

Comment: What do you mean by "*keep* its population limited"? That, to me, would imply that Canada is actively attempting to prevent its population from increasing, which doesn't seem to me to be the case. [Wikipedia states, with references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada#Demographics), that Canada has one of the highest immigration rates in the world and has seen its population increase by 5.2% since 2016.

Comment: This begs the question why Canada would *want* to become a superpower.

Comment: @Philipp, why would China want to become a Superpower? Same reason. Human beings are ambition-driven species.

Comment: The idea that large population + large land = superpower is extremely simplistic, It ignores multiple important historical and cultural factors. And as Philipp says, the assumption that being a superpower is desirable is questionable: for example, why not consider [population happiness](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/happiest-countries-in-the-world) as a goal instead?

Comment: *The USA has a moderately large population, and it is the world's largest economy because of that.* The "logic" of this sentence is **epic**: there are countries more populated to the USA, there are countries less populated than the USA, so it is clear that the reason of the USA being the global superpower is its population.

Comment: @SJuan76, I am talking about the Western countries.

Comment: "This is my personal assessment: The USA has a moderately large population, and it is the world's largest economy because of that." This is assessment is entirely wrong and easily disproven by yourself with the simplest of trivial research.

Answer (score 5):

**Inhabitable territory**
What matters for the OP's argument is not the absolute size of the territory, but how much of it is inhabitable. The facts is that most of Canada is not inhabitable - more than 70% of Canadians live below the 49th parallel, [see here](https://brilliantmaps.com/half-canada/) ([image source](https://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/11/28/a-not-so-straight-story/))
[image]

**Population density**
From the point of view of population density, US is rather densely populated and Canada is on the 39th place - see [the list of countries by population density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_density)
To add to the previous bullet, some countries (like Canada) have huge territory, not all of which is inhabitable - E.g., more than a half of Russia is Siberia, and a great chunk of Saudi Arabia or Jordan are just sands.
[image]

**US as a superpower**
US has risen to the status of a superpower only in the last 100-150 years. This is hardly a spectacular feat in historic proportions, given that some empires had existed for several hundreds or even a thousand of years (Roman empire, Chinese empire). Rise of the US was also helped by a demise of several empires that dominated the world for centuries: The British empire, the French Empire, and the Russian empire/USSR. As the importance of these three has diminished in the course of the last 50 years, it is hard to confirm the link between the rise of the US and the demographic changes over this period. (Image below is taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpower#History))
[image]

Comment: Fun fact: More than 2/3 of Canada's population lives south of the 49th parallel.

Comment: @DavidHammen You are right, the number given in my answer is too low.

Comment: Another fun fact: Forty below zero represents the same temperature on the Fahrenheit and Celsius temperature scales. Parts of Canada where it gets to -40° for weeks on end tend to have a low population. Edmonton, Calgary, Saskatoon, and Winnipeg regularly experience temperatures this low, but not for weeks on end.

Comment: With global warming, couldn't Canada be more inhabitable ?

Comment: @Bregalad it is hard to say how drastic will be the change due to the global warming, and whether it will actually make the cold regions inhabitable - rather than converting them in equally uninhabitable swamps. GW certainly has economical consequences: e.g., it creates more uninhabitable regions in warm countries - e.g., by accelerating growth of deserts. On the other hand, it might make accessible some natural reserves (notably oil) in arctic region - very relevant for Canada and Russia.

Comment: @Bregalad: sometimes defrosting is not so awesome. See Siberia https://www.bbc.co.uk/reel/video/p08rswtc/the-siberian-landscape-scarred-by-climate-change

Comment: @Fizz I think my comment was misunderstood. I didn't intend to say GW is a good thing, I just say it might make Canada more attractive than many other countries who used to be attractive before GW, such as the Mediteranean Bassin...

Comment: I think the area of land is a red herring and is irrelevant to population size. Look at relatively tiny countries like Japan that have multiples of Canada's population. Look at relatively small countries like India that have orders of magnitude of Canada's population. Area only really matters when you intend for the population to not be largely urban. If you live in cities, then you can support housing vertically. The relevance of land area is for food production, if you want to be strategically food secure.

Answer (score 3):

A few issues here:

1. As Roger Vadim excellently said, most of Canada is uninhabitable.  Well, I will caveat that by saying there have been people living in those "uninhabitable" areas for thousands of years and they've been doing just fine, but a "modern" person would not want to live there, for various reasons, the most important one being the climate; it is permanently winter in some parts of Canada, and winter in those areas is even more drastically chilling than in other parts, where it is still very cold.
2. There is very little infrastructure in those areas, because very few people live there.  The government would have to make drastic investment in infrastructure, e.g. telecommunications, in order to entice people to get out of the cities, and those investments may never pay off.  It's a big gamble and one that is probably not politically savvy, particularly when Canada is currently running a national debt/deficit already.
3. The population of a country does not determine its status as a "superpower".  They do correlate (although I would argue with your specific examples; I don't think the UK or France are seen by anyone as a "superpower" to the same extent as the US or China), but for example India, the most populous country on the planet, would be hard pressed to be called a "superpower".  The status of "superpower" is more correlated with defense spending; the more you invest in a large, modern, and powerful military, the more you can wave your military around in other countries' faces and they have to do what you want.  The US spends the most of any country in the world on military, which is why their military is the best and they are (for better or for worse) looked upon as "the world's police".
4. An additional quality of a "superpower" is innovation, which also doesn't correlate with population.  The US has some of the biggest and most innovative companies, e.g. Google and Amazon in the tech space, Tesla in the automotive space, and various natural resource companies, both green and non-green, not to mention SpaceX (another Elon Musk company) which is the as-of-yet only company promising "space tourism" in the world.  Canada simply doesn't have anything near that scale.  China has Tencent and Huawei which compete on a similar level, Japan has Sony, South Korea has Samsung, and so on.  There is a high correlation with top-tier tech companies and being a "superpower", and Canada doesn't have any homegrown tech talent.
5. The other thing is that you are assuming that Canada even wants to become a superpower.  Canada is in very close proximity to the US and has a very close alliance with them (in general; there are various things that have come up particularly in recent years which jeopardize pieces of that relationship, but in general it is very close).  In fact, Canada has such a close relationship that Canada has the longest unprotected border in the world with the US, and has a free trade agreement with the US.  Why would Canada want to put investment into becoming a superpower?  The US is right next door; anything Canada needs, from innovation talent to monetary investment to trade to military support, is all right next door.  It's like building your own grocery store in your house when you live next to Walmart.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't Canada try to make its population grow up to the size of the USA?

I'm going to take a different approach this question. First let's establish how to *make* (as you requested) your population grow. Then show why Canada doesn't take these steps.

There are generally three ways for a country's population to increase (grow).

First is organically. A set of parents in your country have a set of children. The birth rate of the sum of all of these sets of parents is greater than the death rate of your whole population. You can maximize this in several ways: First is minimize death. Second is maximize births. Third is stabilize both rates at some reasonable pace but make sure that only after a person is born another is *allowed* to die. Two of these sound like an authoritarian nightmare to actually implement (imagine laws that state that every person must be married by 25 and produce 3 children at least) and the last one (minimize death) is not really up to a political body to control in reality. I can argue that Canada is at least making an attempt at the minimize death rate strategy but the government doesn't have much control over nature.

The second is inorganically. You can increase your population by taking people from other countries and lose population by the inverse. You gain a net increase when the flow of people in exceed the flow of people out. I can argue that this is likely Canada's main strategy but it has a large disadvantage of being neighbored to another country with the same strategy with a reputation to be the immigration destination. Not to mention there are flaws with this. In order to attract immigrants there must be people willing to leave their own country. So the only real way to maximize this is to make every other country worse off (which is arguably the US strategy...).

The last is by annexation (e.g. the Roman way). You absorb another country (by conquest or peacefully). As there isn't really anywhere left to colonize in this century this really only allows for the old fashion warfare scenario (which Canada likely doesn't want to implement). Canada can also merge with another country, but logistics really only allow for this to happen with neighboring countries. And Canada only shares a land border with one country (the US) and likely would be opposed to merging with it.

Hence, there isn't a viable way for Canada to do so.

Comment: [Ceaucescu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decree_770) tried to do pretty much option #1.  Didn't work very well, good call on the practicalities of 3xing a population.